# Adding Events on DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate

Tags: wpf

I have the following XAML

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocationGroup}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data.GroupList, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}"
                  IsEditable="True"
                  PreviewKeyUp="LocationGroupCombo_OnKeyUp"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=LocationGroup, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

I'm finding that the LocationGroupCombo_OnKeyUp event keeps getting repeatedly called. I think it's because the event handler keeps getting added over and over again.

What's the best practice way to add event handlers to grid editing controls? (I need LostFocus and PreviewKeyUp)

TIA

Comment: For every ```ComboBox``` added you are assigning it the same event handler in code behind but only the ```ComboBox``` being used should be firing the event handler.  Can you also post the code behind as well?

Comment: The code behind doesn't show anything special except the  private void LocationGroupCombo_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) method.

Comment: When exactly does the event handler get called, i.e. what does "repeatedly" actually mean in this case? There seems to be nothing wrong with your approach of attaching the event handlers.

Comment: If I tab in and tab back out - tab/shift tab the event shows once, then twice, three times... Using Debug.WriteLine to view that.